# Passing result from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two Activities (A and B). Activity A consists of Fragment F. How can I pass a result from Activity B to my Fragment F? Here's my code:

**Fragment F**

```
public class FragmentF extends Fragment implements OnCLickListener {

// my editText is in this fragmentf layout
EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentf, container, false);            
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.to_actb);
        b.setOnClickListener(this); 
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

          if (requestCode == 1) {

             if(resultCode == ActivityB.RESULT_OK){      
                 String hey = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("hey.hello.MESSAGE");
                 EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text1);
                 editText.setText(hey); 
             }
          }
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "hey.hello.MESSAGE";

....

    public void to_acta(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        String message = textView.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
        finish();      
    }
```

My problem is, when I clicked the "to_acta" button, nothing is added in my edittext "text1".

Comment: Generally `OnActivityResult` does not execute in `Fragment`. So if your want to pass the result using onActivityResult then it will not execute that method. So even if you are passing the result it will not come in fragment as onActivityResult never executes.

Comment: passing the result to my fragment f using the OnActivityResult..

Comment: Try out starting activity as `getActivity(). startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

Comment: it may be not a good approach but you can set a static variable anywhere whether it is a fragment or an Activity..

Comment: link may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
String hey = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("hey.hello.MESSAGE");
```

with

```
String hey = data.getStringExtra(ActivityB.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Have you read the question carefully? Its asking to pass the result back in Fragment from activity using onActivityResult. And if you are aware `onActivityResult` does not executes in `Fragment`.

Comment: @GrIsHu thanks for your suggestion... I am going to have a mess around it

Comment: I don't know man, but your answer solved my problem. And I'm not the one who voted you down and I can't vote you up 'cos I don't have enough reputation to do so. By the way, the "startActivityForResult(intent, 1);" the 1 is the position of my ActivityB right?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @user2942600 No. 1 is request code to the ActivityB and it can be any non negative and non zero integer. and if you can't vote up, but you can accept answerby clicking the tick mark near to my answer

Comment: @ѕтƒ - ok sir sorry for that

Comment: @GrIsHu why does `onActivityResult` does not executes in `Fragment`?

Comment: @user2942600 you have not accepted any of the answers provided to the questions you asked. Does non of them help you?

Comment: @GrIsHu onActivityResult() will be called in Fragment also. once check that yourself...

Comment: The people who downvoted it, be careful when you are downvoting, even the fellow who asked the question, said it helped but still it is downvoted...